# Laravel 5.8 - Unable to use mail to send emails through Mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun, laravel-5.8

I have spent three days trying to troubleshoot this and run out of ideas.  I am trying to send an email using Mailgun, through Laravel 5.8, when directed to the log, it works fine, but when directed to Mailgun, there are no error messages, no email is sent, so obviously it is not received on the specified address, and nothing shows up in mailgun.

The code for sending is shown below.

```
Mail::to($validatedData['email_address'])->send(new ResetPassword ($account));
```

I have double checked the correct settings in the .ENV (changing this to log, sends it to the log, changing to Mailgun results in no log entry) so I know that is right.

Having purposely put an error in the ResetPassword mailable to make sure it throws and error, it does, so I know its finding that ok. The view being called exists (the text from the view, together with inserted data, appears in the log when directed there).

I am not using Queues.

The settings for mailgun have been double checked, and I have even regenerated the API key to make sure.

Everything looks right, and produces no error message when run, but no email is sent, can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: Please try `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` then run your code.

Comment: Hi, yes tried both, neither of which made any difference.  As answered below, it was an incorrect API URL in the Mailgun documentation that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question!

The Mailgun Api documentation specified api.mailgun.com/v3/**YOURDOMAIN**

However, if you just use api.mailgun.com everything works fine!